# Determine if browser is using mobile data or wifi?

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser

Is there a way to detect if a browser on a mobile device (for example Chrome on Android) is using WiFi or cell data to connect to the internet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation) for that but [it's not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=netinfo) :

```javascript
navigator.connection.addEventListener('typechange', function(){
   console.log(navigator.connection.type);
});
```

### EDIT

The API has changed and the event name is now `change`.

```javascript
navigator.connection.addEventListener('change', function(){
   console.log(navigator.connection.type);
});
```

Comment: Man, 2023 and this API is still useless. On my PC, connected to wired, gigabit ethernet, `effectiveType` is `4g`, `type` is non-existant. On my phone, it does have a `type` of `wifi` or `cellular`. So it's something, but damn near useless across the board. I think we're left to scrabble info together to make an estiated guess, JavaScript style.

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API

But remember that this is experimental for now.

Hope this helps.